# How come my stored procedure does not concatenate strings like normal queries?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Full example is provided for you to try to solve.
The problem is I want to add two columns ('MUNTAX' AND 'SCHTAX') and put the result into a third column ('TOTALTAX') in the table ('house').  However, the columns are prices of type varchar not integer, so I have to remove the '$' sign and ',' before calculating.  And after calculation, must convert back to varchar the total adding back in the '$' and ','.

Where I'm hung up is on getting the total.

Create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `house` (
`ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
`MLS_NO` int(10) default NULL,
`AGENT` varchar(120) default NULL,
`DISP_ORDER` int(4) default NULL,
`ADDR` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '',
`PRICE` varchar(12) NOT NULL default '',
`PRTYPE` varchar(20) default NULL,
`BUILTYPE` varchar(30) default NULL,
`YEAR` varchar(4) default NULL,
`LAREA` decimal(10,0) default NULL,
`ROOM` decimal(10,0) default NULL,
`BEDROOM` decimal(10,0) default NULL,
`BATHROOM` decimal(10,0) default NULL,
`PWDRROOM` decimal(10,0) default NULL,
`GARAGE` decimal(10,0) default NULL,
`PARKING` decimal(10,0) default NULL,
`MUNTAX` varchar(30) default NULL,
`SCHTAX` varchar(30) default NULL,
`TOTALTAX` varchar(30) default NULL,
`DESCR` text,
`DEFAULTPIC` decimal(10,0) default NULL,
`ADTYPE` varchar(100) default NULL,
`DESCR_2` text,
PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`),
KEY `Index_2` (`ADDR`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=122 ;

INSERT INTO `house` (`ID`, `MLS_NO`, `AGENT`, `DISP_ORDER`, `ADDR`, `PRICE`, `PRTYPE`, `BUILTYPE`, `YEAR`, `LAREA`, `ROOM`, `BEDROOM`, `BATHROOM`, `PWDRROOM`, `GARAGE`, `PARKING`, `MUNTAX`, `SCHTAX`, `TOTALTAX`, `DESCR`, `DEFAULTPIC`, `ADTYPE`, `DESCR_2`) VALUES (110, 8620825, 'N', NULL, '5871 FL', '$1,025,000.0', 'DETACHED', 'COTTAGE', NULL, '589', '10', '4', '3', '1', NULL, '4', '$7,774.42', NULL, 'NULL', 'Beautiful');
```

The stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS TotalTaxProc $$

CREATE PROCEDURE TotalTaxProc(IN MLS INT(10), OUT MUNFLO FLOAT(10), OUT SCHINT FLOAT(10), OUT TOTTAX VARCHAR(10))
BEGIN
DECLARE SCH VARCHAR(30);
DECLARE MUN VARCHAR(30);

SET SCHFLO=0.0;
SET MUNFLO=0.0;
SET TOTTAX='';

SELECT MUNTAX FROM house WHERE MLS_NO=MLS INTO MUN;
SELECT SCHTAX FROM house WHERE MLS_NO=MLS INTO SCH;

SET MUNFLO=IFNULL(REPLACE(REPLACE(MUN, '$', ''), ',', ''), 0);
SET SCHFLO=IFNULL(REPLACE(REPLACE(SCH, '$', ''), ',', ''), 0);

SET TOTTAX=CONCAT('$', MUNFLO + SCHFLO ) ;

SET TOTTAX=CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(TOTTAX, SUBSTRING(TOTTAX, -6), 1),',',SUBSTRING(TOTTAX, -6) );


UPDATE house SET TOTALTAX=TOTTAX WHERE MLS_NO=MLS;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

And finally the call,

```
CALL TotalTaxProc(8620825,@MUNINT,@SCHINT,@TOTTAX);
SELECT @MUNINT,@SCHINT,@TOTTAX;
```

So obviously I get just the comma, where the TOTTAX should be giving '$7,774.42'

Comment: I can't plow through all of your code, but it seems that after performing `UPDATE house SET TOTALTAX=TOTTAX` you will modify all the rows in the house table. Is this desired? :)

Comment: @spacediver: I did "plow through" all that code. And what it's really trying to do is `UPDATE house SET c = a + b`. The entire procedure appears to be an attempt to deal with the issue that `a`,`b` and `c` are character columns in format `$9,999.99`.

Comment: @Lawrence: The title of your question is somewhat appropriate. "How come my procedure doesn't concatenate strings like normal queries?" The short answer is, I dunno why all that code is needed, why its necessary to obfuscate the actual (normal SQL) operation you are trying to perform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anywhere in your code where you are setting the @TOTTAX user variable.  (You are modifying a procedure variable TOTTAX which is named similarly, but I don't see a reference to the user variable @TOTTAX anywhere, except in your call and the select.)

Is there a problem with the FORMAT function that prevents you from using it, rather than all those SUBSTRING and SUBSTRING_INDEX functions?

```
SET TOTTAX=CONCAT('$',FORMAT(MUNFLO+SCHFLO,2));
```

The FORMAT() function should take care of making sure there are two digits following the decimal add adding the comma separators, where you won't need to use all those `SUBSTRING` and `SUBSTRING_INDEX` index functions.

---

I'm going to echo spacediver's commment here: the UPDATE statement appears that it will update EVERY row in the house table, with the same value. (It may not be wrong, but it seems oddly peculiar, it would be wrong in most of my UPDATE statements, to not have a JOIN or a WHERE clause, some kind of predicate that specified which rows to update.)

---

**UPDATE**

You've updated your question (made some significant improvements)

It's bizarre that you are running two separate queries to get to different columns from (presumably) the same row. These two separate statements:

```
SELECT MUNTAX FROM house WHERE MLS_NO=MLS INTO MUN;
SELECT SCHTAX FROM house WHERE MLS_NO=MLS INTO SCH;
```

can be replaced with a single select:

```
SELECT MUNTAX, SCHTAX FROM house WHERE MLS_NO=MLS INTO MUN,SCH;
```

As far as I can tell, this line:

```
SET TOTTAX=CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(TOTTAX, SUBSTRING(TOTTAX, -6), 1),',',SUBSTRING(TOTTAX, -6) );
```

does not do anything useful. (It's not at all clear what this needs to do or check that the `FORMAT()` function can't do for you.  Why do you need line, what is it supposed to be doing?

You appear to be casting what is (apparently) a decimal value stored as formatted character strings (ACCCKKK!) to an `INTEGER` value, which is basically losing the two places after the decimal point.

You are then calculating a value as the sum of two other values in the row, and then assigning the result as a "formatted" character value to the TOTALTAX column. Curiously, you are assigning an INTEGER value back to the SCHTAX (character) column, which you were previously expecting to be a decimal value as a formatted string.

The code in your "Final solution" does not pass muster.

I don't see anything that is being accomplished here that couldn't be more easily done (and more easily understood) in a single SQL statement.

Assuming that MLS_NO column is unique (or that you are intending to update a single row using values that are already in the row), then

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TotalTaxProc(IN MLS INT(10))
BEGIN

UPDATE house
   SET TOTALTAX = CONCAT('$',FORMAT(
         IFNULL(REPLACE(REPLACE(MUNTAX, '$', ''), ',', ''), 0) 
       + IFNULL(REPLACE(REPLACE(SCHTAX, '$', ''), ',', ''), 0)
       ,2))
 WHERE MLS_NO=MLS;

END $$
```

This is *so* much easier to understand, without all the procedure variables and SET statements, and all the gyrations.

This statement does differ in behavior from your procedure if there are multiple rows with the same MLS_NO.

This statement assigns a value to the TOTALTAX column which is derived from values *in the same row*. Your procedure, on the other hand, uses values from *some one* row with a matching MLS_NO, to  update *all* rows that have the same matching MLS_NO. (There's no difference if MLS_NO is unique, there's a difference if it is not unique.)

This also differs from the code in your "Final solution", in that isn't losing digits after the decimal point in the calculation of the value to be assigned to TOTALTAX (that could be easily added). (If you want to lose the digits, are you sure you want to do that BEFORE you add them together, or do you want to lose them AFTER you do the addition.

Also this statement differs in that its not reformatting the value of the SCHTAX column.  (That behavior could be easily added, with a simple addition to the same statement.)

Your procedure will change the value of the SCHTAX column from e.g. '$6,543.21' to '6543', not at all clear why you would need to do that.  (I was thinking there was possibly something in the SCHTAX and MUNTAX string values that weren't numeric, like `'/yr'`, `' per year'` or `' (paid 2012)'` or  something else that you were intending to ignore, which is why you were storing this as character and then extracting the decimal value.

---

Comment: Yes, it appears I forgot the where clause for the update. I'm editing it now.

Answer (score 0):

Final solution:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS TotalTaxProc //

CREATE PROCEDURE TotalTaxProc(IN MLS INT(10))
BEGIN
DECLARE SCH VARCHAR(30);
DECLARE MUN VARCHAR(30);
DECLARE SCHFLO FLOAT(15,2);
DECLARE MUNFLO FLOAT(15,2);
DECLARE TOTTAX VARCHAR(30);

SET SCHFLO=0.00;
SET MUNFLO=0.00;
SET TOTTAX='';

SELECT MUNTAX FROM HOUSE WHERE MLS_NO=MLS INTO MUN;
SELECT SCHTAX FROM HOUSE WHERE MLS_NO=MLS INTO SCH;

SET MUNFLO=CAST( IFNULL(REPLACE(REPLACE(MUN, '$', ''),',',''), '0.00') * 100 AS DECIMAL);
SET SCHFLO=CAST( IFNULL(REPLACE(REPLACE(SCH, '$', ''),',',''), '0.00') * 100 AS DECIMAL);


SET TOTTAX=CONCAT('$',FORMAT(MUNFLO/100+SCHFLO/100,2));


UPDATE HOUSE SET TOTALTAX=TOTTAX WHERE MLS_NO=MLS;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

and the call:

```
CALL TotalTaxProc(8620825);
```

Comment: This solution doesn't look final. I don't see how this is going to give you two digits following the decimal point (as shown in your question), because you are effectively casting `MUN` and `SCH` to an INT (and I don't see any multiplication by 100).